# Visual Studio build error "unresolved external symbol WinMain"

Tags: visual-studio

This error is really driving me nuts! How do I fix it?

This is my output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: GenericProjectName, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>MSVCRTD.lib(exe_winmain.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol WinMain referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)
1>C:\generic\path\to\executable.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

And yes, I have Windows selected as the subsystem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it. I looked at an older project's settings, and it had "" (nothing!) selected as the subsystem.

I then changed the subsystem of this project and changed it to Not Set (and also deleted the text just to be sure).

Guess what? It worked somehow!